# How to get row count in all rows?

Tags: sql

```
select id from table;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|  774 |
| 2775 |
+------+
```

return 2 rows

```
select count(id) as count, id from table;
+-------+-----+
| count | id  |
+-------+-----+
|     2 | 774 |
+-------+-----+
```

but return **1 row**

How to return all rows, but with counter in each record ?

```
SQL ???
+-------+------+
| count | id   |
+-------+------+
|     2 | 774  |
|     2 | 2775 |
+-------+------+
```

Comment: MySQL I assume? Most DB engines would complain about `id` not being in a `GROUP BY` or aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, (select count(*) from table) AS TotalRows
FROM table;
```

Although this seems unnecessary, as the total count will not change per row.

Comment: Thanks. Do You have a better solution when `WHERE` clause is more complicated and time-consuming ?

Comment: I don't see one reason you would need to do this. The rowcount should be available to your frontend anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`group by`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
select id, count(id) 
from table
group by id;
```

(BTW, your SQL in question does not work, at least in oracle and AFAIK in MySql)

Comment: if you will use gourp by id and then select count(ID) it should give 1 only for all rows.. just check it out...

Comment: @pratik garg, if ID is unique/primary key, yes. But OP wants a count per id, and based on that I assumed that the id he is mentioning is not unique.

Comment: as per given example it is not like asking count per ID.. that's why i commented on your answer.. please check that again .. may be after your answer he has changed his question... so check and edit your answer/ suggestion

Comment: But what you were telling also currect ... means it is not neccessory that we will get 1 for all rows .. I was wrong in my first comment

Comment: But check what i wanted to say is this query will not give total number of rows / ID per row as marioosh wants in his question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to fetch the rows and get the total count in the same query because its a resource-intensive and you don't want to repeat your joins/conditions/whatever in two queries, under MySQL you can do:

```
# Returns a regular results set
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS foo, bar FROM baz WHERE qux = 'corge' LIMIT 2;
# Returns the total count of found rows (without the LIMIT)
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

If you want the total number of rows after the LIMIT, or don't have a LIMIT at all, you can skip the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

However, generally speaking, counting the total number of rows doesn't scale very well. If you can, find an alternative way that doesn't require you to do that. for example, if its for paging, consider showing only 'next' / 'prev' buttons, without displaying the total number of pages. If you have 30 rows in a page, you can `LIMIT 31` instead of 30, only display the first 30 rows, and check if the 31th row exists to know if a 'next' button should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are useing oracle database you can use count Analytic function also for achieve this task as follow -

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS COUNT, ID FROM TABLE
```

Comment: It can be even simpler: `COUNT(*) OVER ()` (if you meant over the entire rowset).

Comment: I run this (without partition by) also but i was getting 11 rows in .630 sec and with partition by clouse i was getting same 11 rows in .585 sec. i thought with partition by clouse it is faster that's why I include this ... please currect me if I am wrong